# AngularJS: Bind multiple elements with ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I would like to validate multiple elements with ng-model. When every single one of them is true, perform an action.

Is this possible?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Are you using a form?  If yes, you can use form validation in angularjs.  Otherwise you can watch on individual variables and validate whenever they change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AngularJS built-in validation.

Here is a good resource describing how to use it:
 http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation